# Firebase Authentiction using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

We are building a web app using firebase. We are using firebase hosting to host static files like CSS, images, and javascript. We are also using firebase functions to make web app dynamic.

```
const app = express();
...
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.render('index');
});
```

I have a signIn.js in public folder and hosted on Firebase Hosting. When I try to access `"firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier) {}"` function in signin.js, I get an error that "Firebase" is not found.

I want to send OTP on user phone using Firebase. Now I am confused whether we should handle it on the client side in hosted JS files or we have to handle it at server side in server.js.

Also, how could I invoke a function in server.js files hosted on firebase functions from static js file hosted on firebase hosting?

Comment: https://github.com/rhroyston/firebase-v4-auth is newest. ppl seem to like this one though https://github.com/rhroyston/firebase-auth

Answer (score 0):

`firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber` is client side only. You also need to render an invisible reCAPTCHA with it too which can only be done client side. If you are using the Firebase Admin SDK, it allows you to create a user or update an existing user with a phone number but it assumes you verified the number via your own means.

If you need to provide authenticated access to some http endpoints via Firebase Functions, you can send the Firebase ID token of the phone authenticated user to that endpoint (you can get it on the client via `currentUser.getIdToken()`) and verify it via the Admin SDK `verifyIdToken(idToken)`.

Comment: I am using Firebase phone authentication. Now, I am able to send and verify OTP on user phone at the client side. But my concern is that I have to add firebase API key, authDomain, databaseURL in my javascript file to configure firebase. Now user can easily get access to these value and can breach security. @bojeil

Comment: Firebase Auth in web uses reCAPTCHA to verify the domain of the page matches your list of whitelisted domains and also provide anti abuse. In addition your app domain is appended to the SMS message. All these will prevent an attacker from impersonating your app.